# Emulator was deleted while trying to update adb

Tags: android-emulator, adb

I saw a message saying the adb is obsolete when starting the emulator and followed some instruction to updated it. But after it is updated, the emulator program was removed from my computer.

When I am trying to start AVD from Android Studio, it shows [No Emulator Installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvnAV.png). And after clicking on the "Install Emulator" Link, a "Downloading" progress bar shows up and quickly disappeared and the emulator remains missing.

Could anyone help to advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After reinstall the program and trying to use it, I found the emulator.exe was removed by Anti-virus software

[Anti-virus removed android-emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRc1g.png)